# Sum numbers in a range if a cell contains specific character at the end of the number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have range A2:A6. Lets say that A2=3 A3=4k A4=h A5=6k and the A6 is blank.
I need to sum all the numbers in this range ending with a "k".
I have come up with a formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT(ISBLANK(--LEFT(A2:A6;SEARCH("k";A2:A6;1)-1))))
```

But I can not get the (NOT(ISBLANK part working. The above returns 0.
A simplified version of this formula works if the range is only containing numbers ending with a "k", but i need it to skip blanks.
I have found no working solution ideas to get it working.
The correct result for the above range should return 10.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can’t have another formula in column B that pulls out the values ending in k but then also removing the k? Then just sum column B. Make sense? Sometimes it’s easier to break things down then trying to do it all in one formula. It also helps with supportability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with Brad Dixon's comment that a helper column makes things much simpler. I do kinda enjoy solving problems though so I took it for a spin and came up with what I believe should be a little more robust?

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR((RIGHT(A2:A6)="k")*SUBSTITUTE(A2:A6,"k","",1),0))
```

Used as array formula (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. The formula contains 2 main parts:

- `(RIGHT(A2:A6)="k")` checks if the value ends with a `k`, and
- `SUBSTITUTE(A2:A6,"k","",1)` removes that `k` to get the actual value.

[image]

Your formula  (if it worked) would have included any number before a `k` even if that `k` was not at the end (e.g. it would use `6` in `6k2` if it was present), but the above does not.

Also blanks are understood as being equal to 0 in Excel, so adding blanks as well would not have changed the result.

Comment: The above will also not add something like `6kk`.

Comment: Thanks! Both of your solutions work. Indeed I was about to bring a helper column in to this table. Perhaps if the table proves to become too heavy, with all my formulaarrays, then I will do either that or write a macro to make it easier for my PC.

Answer (score 1):

Try an array formula.

I made this data example:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I want to sum only values in cells A2 and A4 (the ones ending with the char K). The result is 6. The formula I have used is this one:

`=SUM(IF(RIGHT($A$1:$A$4;1)="k";SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$4;"k";"")+0))`

> To make this formula work, it must be entered as array formula, that
>   means, you type it as normal, but instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>
>   to confirm, you must press
>   <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or it won't work.

The `+0` part in the formula is to autoconvert the string obtained after replacing K to a number.

Hope you can adap this to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT(A2:A6)="k")*(IFERROR(--LEFT(A2:A6),0)))
```

you do not care if it is blank because the value of the blank is 0 and does not affect your sum.  the problem is that the left is not always a number.  Wrapping the LEFT function in IFERROR and setting it to zero treats non numerics as as false or 0.

Due to the IFERROR function inside the SUMPRODUCT, the formula needs to be entered as an array function.  Use <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when you enter your formula.  You will know you have done it right when { } appear around your formula.  They cannot be added manually.

[image: poc]

NOTE:  Replace the `,` separators with `;` to match your system

Comment: What about `40k`?

Comment: example question only uses single charaters

Comment: Example question contains examples only, but the question itself mentions 'sum *numbers*', which 40 is very much a number, unless OP goes to specify those number are only 1 digit in length.

Comment: then supply a better representative sample

Comment: Thanks, in my case above I use only single non-number characters at the end of the number, but the number itself can be a single or double digit. The solution given by Jerry works fine for my case.

Comment: Agreed it is a more generic solution and that it suits your needs better.  This was just an alternative approach that cut corners based on the data at hand.  Good luck with your project.